# Executable from Python returns array

Tags: python, serial-port, difference, modbus

I am new to python programming on Raspberry Pi 3.

I have written a code in Python using IDLE 3.
It reads the values from MODBUS device, and returns the value as integer.

```
def ReadParameter(Parameter):
    Value1=65635
    message[3]=Parameter
    #CRC (Cyclical Redundancy Check) Calculation
    CRC = CRCcal(message)

    #index11= CRC Lo
    message[len(message) - 2] = CRC[0]#CRCLo
    #index12 = CRC Hi
    message[len(message) - 1] = CRC[1]#CRCHi
    for item in message:
        ser.write (struct.pack('>B', item))

    Value1=0xFF
    x=ser.readline()
    if len(x)>3:
        Value1=x[3]
        Value1 = Value1*256
        Value1 +=x[4]
        print ('Value of Parameter:', Parameter, ' is : ', Value1)
    return (Value1)
```

The above works fine with IDLE3 as shown below:

```
Value of Parameter: 0  is :  1000
Value of Parameter: 5  is :  0
Value of Parameter: 4  is :  0
Value of Parameter: 3  is :  0
Value of Parameter: 2  is :  0
Value of Parameter: 1  is :  0
```

When I make an executable file, it shows:

```
('Value of Parameter:', 0, ' is : ', '\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\xe8')
('Value of Parameter:', 5, ' is : ', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
('Value of Parameter:', 4, ' is : ', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
('Value of Parameter:', 3, ' is : ', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
('Value of Parameter:', 2, ' is : ', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know what happens in the IDLE3 environment, in particular not how it manages to print so nicely, but in the second case, apparently `x` is a string, and then the code takes the third character, applies *256, which repeats it 256 times, and appends the fourth character, and at the end a tuple is printed, which is exactly what you see.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply. But how to solve this problem?

Comment: This problem is solved. The x=ser.readline() returns a list and NOT an Array. So you have process list, NOT an array. I used the following instruction :         Value1 = struct.unpack('>H', x[3:5])[0] print(Value1)

Comment: During this project I noted that the code running in Python is different that the code running through the executable file, typically when it comes to processing the list. Running Source code through Python and running the executable file created using Pythion, are NOT 100% same. There is a difference, I cannot put a finger, on what exactly is the difference due to shortage of time, but will be curious to find it out and discuss it here.

Comment: For reading 16 bit number from MODBUS, I used: Value1 = struct.unpack('>H', x[3:5])[0]     and for reading 32 bit number is used Value1 = struct.unpack('>I', x[3:7])[0]